# PHP message "Error: No database selected", concernig this script

Tags: php, database

I have this script, but i don't know what could be wrong here when I hit "post" button on the main page. Where the error can come from?

The page script:

```
<?php 
session_start();
    include("dbconnection.php");
 function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

$messages = clean($_POST['message']);
$user =clean($_POST['name']);
$pic =clean($_POST['name1']);
$poster =clean($_POST['poster']);

$sql="INSERT INTO message (messages, user, picture, date_created, poster)
VALUES
('$messages','$user','$pic','".strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))."','$poster')";

mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET picture = '$pic' WHERE FirstName='$user'");
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
header("location: lol.php");
exit();

$name=$_POST['name'];
$pic=$_POST['name1'];

mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET picture = '$pic' WHERE FirstName='$name'");
?>
```

This is the dbconnect file:

```
$con = mysql_connect("hostname","username","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("asl", $con);
?>
```

Comment: show us the dbconnection.php file please

Comment: Your error is in `dbconnection.php`

Comment: Wow, this code has *a lot* wrong with it. Using old mysql driver, insecure handling of data, inaccessible code, suppressing errors (where it makes no sense to do so), not selecting a database. Where to begin...

Comment: Why do you display your crenditials

Comment: OP, you should change your database password. Quickly.

Comment: Make sure your 'as1' database exists first.

Answer (score 0):

this errors seems to be caused by either selecting `wrong database` or `not selecting it.`

check `dbconnection.php` and for this line in it

```
mysql_select_db("your_database_name",$your_connection);
```

See whether this line is present and pointing to database or not and make sure this databse exists

**Update** It seems that your file is not being included try `require()` so that it produces fatal error and you can see file s being including or not

```
 require("dbconnection.php"); // will produce fatal errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have selected your db using mysql_select_db

```
mysql_connect('hostname','username','password') or die("not able to connect");
mysql_select_db('myDatabase');
```

And mysql_ extensions are deprecated.. Dont use it

Answer (score 0):

First of all mysql_connect is outdated and unsecure, better use PDO instead

```
    <?php 

    session_start();
    include("dbconnection.php");
    function clean($str) {
            $str = @trim($str);
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                        $str = stripslashes($str);
            }
            return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        }

    $messages = clean($_POST['message']);
    $user =clean($_POST['name']);
    $pic =clean($_POST['name1']);
    $poster =clean($_POST['poster']);

    $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO message (messages, user, picture, date_created, poster) VALUES (:messages, :user, :picture, :date_created, :poster)");
    $sql->bindParam(':messages', $messages);
    $sql->bindParam(':user', $user);
    $sql->bindParam(':picture', $pic);
    $sql->bindParam(':date_created', strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));
    $sql->bindParam(':poster', $poster);

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE messages SET picture = :picture WHERE FirstName = :user");
    $stmt->bindParam(':picture', $pic);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);
    $stmt->execute();


    if (!$sql->execute())
    {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }


    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $pic=$_POST['name1'];

    $stmt_2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE messages SET picture = :picture WHERE FirstName = :name");
    $stmt_2->bindParam(':picture', $pic);
    $stmt_2->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt_2->execute();

    header("location: lol.php");

    ?>
```

This is the dbconnect file:

```
    <?php
            //Connect to sql db
            try {
                    $user_db = "username";
                    $pass_db = "password";
                    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=asl', $user_db, $pass_db);

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
                    die();
            }

    ?>
```